# Use of H1 Class for other H tags

Tags: css, seo

If you have mutliple `h2` tags on a given page, but you wanted to have it look like your `H1` styling, will having the `h1` class for mulitple `h2` tags have any SEO implications:

```
<html>
<h2 class="h1">blah blah </h2>

.
.
.

<h2 class="h1">something else </h2>.
.
.

<h2 class="h1">something diferent </h2>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary purpose of heading tags when it comes to SEO is to indicate the most important content in a hierarchy (h1 tags indicating the most important content). However, the more of a certain heading tag you use, especially for h1 tags, the less weight they will carry in SEO.

That is why if you want big text, for say, a button, but the text is not relevant to your website, it is better to use  or

and style it with CSS because giving the text an h1 tag would indicate that it is highly relevant to your website.

The CSS styling itself won't have any bearing on SEO, so to answer your question, **no**, having the h1 class for multiple h2 tags would not have any SEO implications and is actually the best move compared to using h1 tags instead of h2 to get the formatting you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yes, definitely better to multiple h2 than multiple h1 tags. Thought it seemed a little odd to call the style "H1" (the coveted h1 tag) and maybe it would be better to create a different class with identical style of an "H1" to avoid confusion. 
With that said if designating classes with "h1" has no SEO impact then its a moot point.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2 class="h1">something diferent</h2>
```

For using this you need to define default display properties for **`.h1 class`** same as `<h1> tag`

```
.h1 {
display: block;
font-size: 2em;
margin-before: 0.67em;
margin-after: 0.67em;
margin-start: 0;
margin-end: 0;
font-weight: bold; }
```

So it will not have any SEO implication as we do style h1, h2 etc tags by assign class to and defining font-style.

we can do this same by defining a different class and giving the same properties like h1 tag

```
<h2 class="same_style">something diferent </h2>

.same_style {
display: block;
font-size: 2em;
margin-before: 0.67em;
margin-after: 0.67em;
margin-start: 0;
margin-end: 0;
font-weight: bold; }
```